Cannot install ggxmean on R version 4.2.3 (2023-03-15)
I am still learning basic R. When I install the package ggxmean by devtools::install_github("EvaMaeRey/ggxmean"), it shows:

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘devtools’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
namespace ‘htmltools’ 0.5.3 is already loaded, but >= 0.5.7 is required

Tried as follow:
update.packages("htmltools"). The screen has "Backing up R session" and lastly show "unable to execute".
install.packages("htmltools")

  There is a binary version available but the source
  version is later:
          binary  source needs_compilation
htmltools  0.5.7 0.5.8.1              TRUE

Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘ggxmean’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages

My R version 4.2.3 (2023-03-15). When I updated R version, I could not use other installed R packages. So I use this version on MacOs 12.7.6.
Is there a possible way to install ggxmean with the current R version?

to run install_github you do not need the full devtools package. Just install remotes install.packages('remotes') then remotes::install_github('EvaMaeRey/ggxmean')

It worked for me. Thanks a lot.
